# Which book is all about the Hosts?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, product-identification, werewolf-the-forsaken

I want to know more about the hosts.
The Azlu and the Beshilu.

There is a little about them in Werewolf Core.
A friend told me there was a book that was all about them,
but couldn't recall the name.

What is that book?

I presume it has all the other obscure [hosts listed on the wiki](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Hosts_%28WTF%29) as well.

Answer (score 3):

The book you want is [Predators](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/2402/Predators?it=1). It's the one with all the Hosts you list.